# Unknown Symbol Appear in the application window in Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox, language-support, oracle, windows-11

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 on my Windows 11 system using Oracle VirtualBox. But when I open some apps, these symbols are appearing:

[image: Gparted screenshot]

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your VM and choose the `settings`. In the VM settings, navigate to the '`Display`' section and ensure that '`Enable 3D Acceleration`' is **checked**. If it's already checked, verify that the `Graphic controller` settings are **correct** and there's no '`Invalid setting detected`' message at the bottom of the settings window.

*Additionally, I've noticed that Virtual Box's 3D acceleration option can sometimes be the culprit. If it's checked, try unchecking the box and recheck your output. This should resolve any issues you're facing.*

[image: Virtual Box Display Settings Page]